# How do i update text graphics in flashpunk?

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is a class i made that will be used to make the items for a menu i'm working on.

```
package  
{
    import net.flashpunk.Entity;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Graphiclist;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Stamp;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Text
    import net.flashpunk.FP;
    import net.flashpunk.utils.Input;

    public class MenuItem extends Entity 
    {       
        public var label:Text;  //public text var to display label      
        public var amount:Text;
        public var amountText:String;

        public function MenuItem(x:Number=0, y:Number=0, text:String = "", amnt:Number = 0) 
        {
            super(x, y);

            label = new Text(text, 10, 10, { size: 20, color: 0xFFFFFF, width: 111, wordWrap: false, align: "center" } ); //format text
            label.y = 25; //place text
            label.x = 0; // place text

            amountText = amnt.toString();

            amount = new Text(amountText, 10, 10, { size: 20, color: 0xFFFFFF, width: 111, wordWrap: false, align: "center" } ); 
            amount.y = 25;
            amount.x = 50;
            graphic = new Graphiclist(label, amount);   //set graphic list (png and text)

            setHitbox(110, 70, 0, 0);
        }
         override public function update():void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What i'm looking for is how to update the amnt using the update function. 
But my knowledge of flashpunk is not great and i;m not sure how i would go about doing this exactly. please and thank you! if what i'm asking is unclear please contact me so i can specify whatever is needed.

Comment: As far as I know, the update method will be called multiple times. Do you want to update the text each time or conditionally? Also what would you want the text to be set to? Thanks

Comment: Basically, I would the text to display the attack power of the player on a menu. So if for some reason the attack power changes I would like it to change in this menu also.

Comment: Am i supposed to use the update function of the world? or do i do it in one of the entities?